# Cambiar binding/texto de una label con un switch

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Tengo esta interfaz gráfica:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde la label **"Weight: 70 kg"** muestra el peso que ha sido seleccionado en el slider debajo del label por parte del usuario.

Existe alguna manera para que cuando active el switch, la label que muestra el peso cambie de kg a lbs y viceversa?

- Switch activo muestra peso en libras.
- Switch inactivo muestra peso en kilos.

Ejemplo en la imagen esta **"Weight: 70kg"** una vez activado el switch se visualizara **"Weight: 155 lbs"**.

```
    <Label  x:Name="Imperial_System_Label"
                    Grid.Row="3"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                    Text="Imperial System" 
                    TextColor="Black"
                    FontSize="22"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

            <Switch x:Name="Switch"
                    Grid.Row="4"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    Toggled="Handle_Toggled"/>

            <Label x:Name="Height_Label"
                   Grid.Row="5" 
                   Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                   BindingContext="{x:Reference Height_Slider}"
                   Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat='Height: {0:F0} cm'}" 
                   TextColor="Black"
                   FontSize="22"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

            <Slider Grid.Row="6" 
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                    x:Name="Height_Slider" 
                    Maximum="240" 
                    Minimum="135" 
                    Value="170"/>

            <Label x:Name="Weight_Label"
                   Grid.Row="7" 
                   Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                   BindingContext="{x:Reference Weight_Slider}"
                   Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat='Weight: {0:F0} kg'}" 
                   TextColor="Black"
                   FontSize="22"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   VerticalOptions="Center"/>

            <Slider Grid.Row="8" 
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                    x:Name="Weight_Slider" 
                    Maximum="400" 
                    Minimum="35" 
                    Value="70"/>
```

La label tiene un binding `Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat='Weight: {0:F0} kg'}"`  exite algún modo de cambiarlo cuando el switch venga activado?

```
 namespace FitnessCalculatorApp
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class BMICalculatorPage : ContentPage
    {
        public BMICalculatorPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        void Handle_Toggled(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ToggledEventArgs e)
        {
            String WeightLabelText = Weight_Label.Text;

            if (e.Value.Equals(false))
            {
                Weight_Slider.Maximum = 900;
                Weight_Slider.Minimum = 75;
                Weight_Slider.Value = 65;
                Weight_Label.Text = "Weight: " + Weight_Slider.Value + " lbs";
            }       

        } 
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Trate de crear una viewmodel:

```
namespace FitnessCalculatorApp.Models
{
    class BMICalculatorPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        string weight = string.Empty;

        public string Weight
        {
            get => weight;
            set
            {
                if (weight == value)
                {
                    return;
                }

                onActivateSwitch(nameof(weight));
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void onActivateSwitch(string weight)
        {
            weight = "new weight";
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(weight));
        }
    }
}
```

Y modifique el binding de la label weight:

```
  <Label x:Name="Weight_Label"
         Text="{Binding Weight}"/>
```

Pero no logro cambiar el texto del label a "new weight" al activar el switch.

Comment: Ponga el método Handle_Toggled y el código del viewmodel

Comment: En que ayudaria eso.

Comment: Podes heredar INotifyPropertyChanged en tu modelo. Si colocas la clase que manejas el objeto, te ayudo.

Comment: OK, no estoy seguro cual sea la clase que mencionas, pondre el codigo cs de la UI.

Comment: Deberias manejar la vista con un modelo por detras en el BindingContext. Te dejo el enlace del canal de Xamarin Forms. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pr03CYqhFr4&list=PLM75ZaNQS_FaEPpqVjfQdnFaSR1EWCeNZ

Comment: Trate de crear una viewmodel basandome en el video, pero no logro que funcione.

Comment: Tienes algunos errores, ahora te creo una respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes colocar el evento en toggled en tu switch y cuando esta activado cambias tu texto en el label y ahi puedes usar correctamente la interface INotifyPropertyChanged.

Te coloque unos cambios, primero mas que nada si tu bindingContext en tu label es tu slider, no te funciona la interface porque le haces otro binding en lugar de la propiedad que tu editaste para realizar dicho trabajo y la interface grafica nunca se entera de esos cambios.

Segundo en tu interface tenias algunas lineas mal escritas, te faltaba setear tu valor que traias y en el evento le pasabas un texto estatico.

Te agregue el evento sobre el slider, cuando este cambia el valor, ese valor se pasa a tu propiedad weight y esta propiedad le avisa a la interface grafica.

Hice unos cambios para que funcione bien todo ahora debes terminar acomodarla a tus gustos y necesidades.

```
 public partial class BMICalculatorPage : ContentPage
{
    BMICalculatorPageViewModel bmi = new BMICalculatorPageViewModel();
    public Pagina3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = bmi;

    }

    private void Switch_Toggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Value)
        {
            bmi.Weight =$"{Weight_Slider.Value * 2.205} lbs.";
        }

    }

    private void Weight_Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        bmi.Weight = e.NewValue.ToString();
    }
}
public class BMICalculatorPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string weight = string.Empty;

    public string Weight
    {
        get
        {
            return weight;
        }

        set
        {
            if (weight == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            weight = value;
            onActivateSwitch(nameof(Weight));
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void onActivateSwitch(string weight)
    {

        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(weight));
    }
}

     <Label  x:Name="Imperial_System_Label"
                Grid.Row="3"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                Text="Imperial System" 
                TextColor="Black"
                FontSize="22"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

        <Switch x:Name="Switch"
                Grid.Row="4"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Toggled="Switch_Toggled"/>

        <Label x:Name="Height_Label"
               Grid.Row="5" 
               Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
               BindingContext="{x:Reference Height_Slider}"
               Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat='Height: {0:F0} cm'}" 
               TextColor="Black"
               FontSize="22"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

        <Slider Grid.Row="6" 
                Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                x:Name="Height_Slider" 
                Maximum="240" 
                Minimum="135" 
                Value="170"/>

        <Label x:Name="Weight_Label"
               Grid.Row="7" 
               Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
               Text="{Binding Weight, StringFormat='Weight: {0:F0}'}" 
               TextColor="Black"
               FontSize="22"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center"/>

        <Slider Grid.Row="8" 
                Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                x:Name="Weight_Slider" 
                Maximum="400" 
                Minimum="35" 
                Value="70" ValueChanged="Weight_Slider_ValueChanged"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Es importante que profundize en el patrón mvvm ya que la documentación y ejemplos van a estar en mvvm. En este caso al ser un toggle no permite el uso de commands pero lo normal es que los eventos se manejen por medio de commands. Este ejemplo podría ayudarle:

Modifique el xaml como sigue:

```
 <Grid>



     <Switch 
                    Grid.Row="4"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                IsToggled="{Binding Toggled}"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center">

        </Switch>
        <Label 
                   Grid.Row="5" 
                   Grid.ColumnSpan="3"

                   Text="{Binding Height}" 
                   TextColor="Black"
                   FontSize="22"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

 <Label 
                   Grid.Row="7" 
                   Grid.ColumnSpan="3"

                   Text="{Binding Weight}" 
                   TextColor="Black"
                   FontSize="22"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   VerticalOptions="Center"/>

    </Grid>
```

Luego cree un ViewModel o modifique el que ya hizo con este código:

```
public class vmMain:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool toggled;

    public vmMain()
    {
        Height = "70 cm";

        Weight = "70 cm";
    }



    private string height;

    private string weight;



    public string Height { get => height; set { height = value;NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Height)); } }
    public string Weight { get => weight; set { weight = value;NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Weight)); } }
    public bool Toggled { get => toggled; set { toggled = value;

            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Toggled));

            handle();

        } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {

        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }


    private void handle()
    {
        if (Height.Contains("cm"))
        {
            Height = "155 lbs";

        }
        else
        {
            Height = "70 cm";
        }

        if (Weight.Contains("cm"))
        {
            Weight = "155 lbs";

        }
        else
        {
            Weight = "70 cm";
        }



    }


}
```

Y por último en el code behind de la content page modifiquela de la siguiente manera:

```
public partial class BMICalculatorPage : ContentPage
{

    vmMain vm=new vmMain();// La instancia del VIEW MODEL

    public BMICalculatorPage ()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = vm;
    }


}
```